# How to override ajax=false so it switches to loaded dom page if exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a few item htmls, each of which contains a single JQM-page.
I also have an index page. It is a multi-JQM-paged html, with each JQM-page as a category listing the items.

```
  index.html                  item1.html           item2.html
  +------------------+        +--------+--------+  +--------
  |+-------+         |     +--|Cat.    |    Next|->|Cat.
  ||.cont- |         |     |  +--------+--------+  |--------
  ||ent    |+-------+|<----+  |                 |  |
  |+-------+|#cat1  ||        |                 |  |
  |         |       ||        |bla bla bla      |  |bla bla
  |         |link1+---------->|                 |  |
  |         |link2  ||        |                 |  |
  |         +-------+|        +-----------------+  +--------
  |+-------++-------+|
  ||#cat2  ||#cat3  ||
  ||       ||       ||
  ||link4  ||link3  ||
  ||       ||       ||
  |+-------++-------+|
  +------------------+
```

Currently I can link from index to the item, with smooth ajax loading. However I realized that if I want to link back from item to index#cat1, I need to use `data-ajax='false'` as index is a multi-page html. (I can't use `data-rel='back'` because the previous page isn't always index.html).

If I use `ajax='false'`, I lose the smooth transition if I switch between list and items often (each switching back to list is a full reload). e.g.:

*-full-load->* index#cat1 *-ajax-load->* item2 *-full-load(again)->* index#cat1

**Question**

I want:

*-full-load->* index#cat1 *-ajax-load->* item2 *-ajax-switch-to-already-loaded->* index#cat1

How can I override jquery mobile logic so that when the `data-ajax='false'` link is clicked, it first searches to see if that index#cat1 page is already in the dom? If it is, then just switch to that JQM-page. If it does not exist, do a full loading of the index#cat1 without ajax (like the default behaviour).

**Keep in mind that an user can start from item1.html and navigate to index.html#cat1.**

I know I would need to markup each JQM-page with some custom attributes, like `data-full-url="index.html#cat1"` to make it easier to search for existing pages. However my main weakness is how I can change existing Jquery Mobile linking logic.

Comment: Can't do it without http://www.asciiflow.com/

Comment: Why not just separate each pseudo-page into different HTML documents? What are you gaining by creating this complex logic? If it's about perceived load-time then I suggest using separate documents and using the `data-prefetch` attribute to avoid unwanted navigation lag.

Answer (score 0):

I have created your situation in following fiddles.

1) index page: http://jsfiddle.net/nachiket/RpZW7/
2) detail item page: http://jsfiddle.net/nachiket/cHmhW/  (this one is already linked in index page fiddle)

I haven't used data-ajax='false', Does it solve your problem? If not, Please update this fiddles to your exact situation,so can help better.

Comment: thanks. So my problem is, if my user starts from item page, I want to allow it to link back to index#cat1. My current version is at http://jsfiddle.net/lulalala/nuL6h/2/

Comment: well, I dont think, it will be easy to achieve transition without Ajax. What I do is I keep one page app only, and navigate through ajax and maintain history/refresh using hash changes. 
so, If its easier load item1 and item2 using Ajax only. you can still request server for loading content of item1 and item2, but it will provide only body part, rather than full HTML page.

Comment: the firs time index is loaded, obviously it won't be an ajax load. A case would be: item1 --full-load-> index#cat1 --ajax-load-> item2 --js-switch-> index#cat1

Comment: Bounty made me try harder, and may Be, I have found a solution. 
But it requires your item page to know ID/key of category page.
Here is the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/nachiket/nuL6h/6/

Comment: thanks but it will keep reload index page, I need a javascript solution which is outside the JQM framework

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle seems down, is this close to your example?

I put that in a local server

For the item1's back button you can put the full url: `http://localhost/home.html#cat1`, it will also work

home.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html manifest="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<link type="text/css">

</link>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>home</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        hello home
        <a href="home.html#cat1" type="button">cat1</a>
        <a href="home.html#cat2" type="button">cat2</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="cat1">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>cat1</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        hello cat1
        <a href="#home" type="button">home</a>
        <a href="item1.html" type="button">see item1</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="cat2">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>"cat2</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        hello cat2
        <a href="#home" type="button">home</a>
    </div>
</div>

    </body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

item1.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html manifest="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<link type="text/css">

</link>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="item1Home">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>item1's home</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        hello item1
        <a href="home.html#cat1" type="button" rel="external">back?</a>
    </div>
</div>


    </body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: yes this is my current solution, but what I want is to avoid reloading the whole home.html if it has been loaded previously

Comment: the browser will use its cache, more easily if you keep ajax navigation

Comment: even with cache it is noticeably slow, as my index page is quite big. And trying to have ajax navigation is the problem I want to solve, not something I try to avoid.